# Why can't I use [PSCustomObject] on $matches within pipeline?

Tags: powershell

If I do the following

```
@("a", "b") |
  % { if ($_ -match "(?<x>a)") { $matches; } } | 
  % { [PSCustomObject]$_; }
```

I get

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
x                              a
0                              a
```

But if I define the property explicitly:

```
@("a", "b") |
  % { if ($_ -match "(?<x>a)") { $matches; } } |
  % { [PSCustomObject]@{x = $_.x} }
```

I get

```
x
-
a
```

What is the difference here and why first attempt does not return a custom object with `x` as a property?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is that when you do this:

```
@("a", "b") |
  % { if ($_ -match "(?<x>a)") { $matches; } } | 
  % { [PSCustomObject]$_; }
```

Is that it's calling `getenumerator()` on `$matches` in the script block, and sending the result of that down the pipeline, not the ref to the hash table.

`[PSCustomObject]$Matches` is passing the actual reference to the hash table, and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this kind of makes sense, but _why_ is it calling `GetEnumerator()` in the first case? Notice that in the second case I can successfully use `$_` as a hashtable. Is there something special about type of `$_`?

Comment: The difference is not in the variables, but how they're being used. Inside the script block $matches is an expression, and the command process is going to evaluate it by calling it's default method (getenumerator()). That's the same thing that would happen if you'd do the match and then output $matches at the command line. In the second case $_.x is a different expression and requires a different method of evaluation.

Comment: However I use exactly the same script block in both cases. Is `$_` a `Hashtable` in both cases? It seems so, but then why can't I cast it to a custom object?

Comment: It's not really a hashtable in either one.  After it's gone through getenumerator(), it's now a collection of DictionaryEntry objects.  There will be 2 of them.  Only one of them will have a key named 'x', and result in successful creation of an object.

Comment: But if I do `@("a", "b") | % { if ($_ -match "(?<x>a)") { $matches; } } | % { $_.GetType() }` I get only one row saying `Hashtable`, instead of two rows of `DictionaryEntry`.

Comment: That I cannot explain, but the output you're getting from the first example is identical to what you get if you use {$matches.getenumerator()} in the script block of that If.

Comment: True, but if I add `GetEnumerator()` to the second sample, the result is different. Obviously the pipeline does not change behavior of previous parts based on following ones, so I assume `GetEnumerator()` call is inserted into the last block -- the question is why.

Comment: In the second example, you're explicitly creating a new hash table in the second foreach, using output from the first foreach.

Comment: OK, ignoring hashtables for a moment, there is a clear difference between `@("a", "b") | % { if ($_ -match "(?<x>a)") { $matches.GetEnumerator() } } | % { $_.x }` and `@("a", "b") | % { if ($_ -match "(?<x>a)") { $matches } } | % { $_.x }`. So I do not think it calls `GetEnumerator()` in the first block.

Comment: Ok, then don't mark that as an answer. But we need to be done with the comments on this thread.

Comment: My goal is a proper understanding of the situation, not just deciding whether to tick the box or not. But it is easy to agree that StackOverflow is a poor platform for a proper discussion. Thank you for your time spent on this.